# Input variable assignments using dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

How do I store user input in a dictionary, for example first value is **x** the the second value is **10**. Then those input values will be stored in a dictionary and will be printed:`"x = 10"`

Similar to this I have tried with default values

```
phonebook = {"John" : 938477566,"Jack" : 938377264,"Jill" : 947662781}
   for name, number in phonebook.items():
print("Phone number of %s is %d" % (name, number))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
diction = {}
name = input()
number = int( input())
diction[name] = number
print(diction)
```

This is not the best or the most elegant way to do it but I think it is what you are asking

Comment: Don't call your dictionary `dict`, that name should be reserved for the actual data structure, not a variable name

Comment: What if i wanted to print it with a format like Name = Number? not {'X': '15') or have multiple entries? Like NAme, Number, Code, Street?

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
dict_storage = {}
stop_word = 'stop'

while True:
    variable_name = input('Please insert variable name: ')

    if variable_name == stop_word:
        break

    variable_value = input('Please insert variable value: ')

    if variable_value == stop_word:
        break

    dict_storage[variable_name] = variable_value

for k, v in dict_storage.items():
    print(f'{k} = {v}')


# output: 
# Please insert variable name: x
# Please insert variable value: 10
# Please insert variable name: stop
# x = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def input_name_and_number():
    print('-'*10)
    phonebook = {}
    while True:
        name, number = input('Enter name.\t'), int(input('Enter number\t'))
        phonebook[name] = number
        print("Phone number of %s is %d" % (name, number))
        print('-'*10)
        add_more = input('Do you wish to add more contacts?(y/n)\t')
        print('-'*10)
        if  add_more == 'n':
            print('--Input of contacts complete--')
            print('-'*10)
            break

    print(' ')
    return(phonebook)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    phonebook = input_name_and_number()
    print(phonebook)
```